# Normal operator proof - is $TT = T^*T^*$ says T is normal operator?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, operator-algebras

Is it true what i wrote in title?
if yes, how can I prove it?
I have a question and I reached that point ( I need to show if $T^2=\frac 1 2 (T+T^*)$ so conclude T is normal operator).
I have the answer to that question from my exerciser at study, but I dont want to look at solution yet ( so posted here to ask if it says its normal ).

Comment: No. the 2x2 nilpotent jordan block is a counterexample

Comment: ahh aww... I thought I was getting good here :\ how am I supposed to prove normal then.. I guess I will look at answers, thanks!

Comment: an hint is: try to isolate $T^*$, and then write down the normality condition

Comment: yea, sadly I already looked at it :\
I didnt think of it, its as you said.
Now I am stuck at another thing regarding to the question, but I will just look at the answer.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general comment and not to leave an unanswered post, every time you can write $T^*$ in terms of $T$, be it a polynomial or even a continuous/Borel function through functional calculus, the operator will be normal. Simply because $T$ commutes with $f(T)$, and so if $T^*=f(T)$ then $T$ is normal.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer :)